# mysql query optimization 100 000 records with left outer join

Tags: mysql, optimization, normalization

i have a clients table, and 100,000 records in it.

And also clients has alot of related tables, where stores a related data.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `clients2`.`id`) 
  FROM `clients2` as `clients2` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` as `users` 
    ON (    `clients2`.`user_id`=`users`.`id` 
         and users.status!=5 
         and clients2.status!=5
       ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `private_data` as `privateData` 
  ON (    `users`.`person_id`=`privateData`.`id` 
      and clients2.status!=5
     )
```

This is only 2 joins, but my real query has 5-7 joins. And it's very slow with 100,000 records. About 0.5 sec.

My database is very normalized. And it seems like i need to denormalize it now. 
Or maybe anyone can recommend a good solution ?

Comment: Have you created any indexes? Is this an OLAP or OLTP?

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization , follow NF (Normal form) to optimize your database. **Indexing** is also important.

Comment: please post the execution plan, as well as table definitions

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably use some of the inbuilt optimization techniques of Mysql in itself for joins.

[LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the DB is normalized, you could probably use a 'normal' join in the query.. 
That should speed it up a lot.